# Trying to add a carriage return to a powershell script

Tags: powershell

This is my first powershell script and it works great, it finds files that are 30 minutes old and emails the results, I just want to add a carriage return so the output is more readable.

Output looks like this:
J:\folder\lap001\testfile J:\folder\lap001\testfile2 J:\folder\lap001\testfile3 J:\folder\lap002\testfile

```
#Command to get list of folders with logfiles where the logfile is at least 30 minutes old.
$varlogfile = Get-ChildItem -Path "j:\folder" -Recurse -Include "testfile*" | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -le ((Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30))}

#Email setup
$SMTPServer = "server"
$From = "Administrator"
$To = "something"
$Subject = "A Logfile older than 30 minutes has been detected"
$Body = "Logfile(s) older than 30 minutes have been detected in the following folders:

$varlogfile

Please login and attempt to process the files manually, if the manual process fails, open a ticket with something.

From the Admin
"

#Command to send email
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer

exit 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok that should not be too hard after this line

```
$varlogfile = Get-ChildItem -Path ....
```

Add another line to get your newline delimited text

```
$varlogfile =  $varlogfile -join "`r`n"
```

When arrays get cast as strings they just have a space inserted. `-join` add a newline instead